# Replace/delete all " in a txt file using batch code

Tags: batch-file, txt

I have a batch file that converts input from the user and writes it into a text file. However, the output in the file contains double-quotes  (`"`), which I don't want. Is it possible to search for `"` in a text file and replace/delete them using batch code?

e.g. output(In a txt.file):  `"|Sample text|"` to `|Sample text|`

I tried the following code but it does not work

```
%FILENAME% = name of the txt.file

:CLEARC
(Get-Content %FILENAME%.txt) -replace '"', ' '| Set-Content -encoding ASCII %FILENAME%.txt
```

Comment: ```(Get-Content %FILENAME%.txt) -replace '"', ' '| Set-Content -encoding ASCII %FILENAME%.txt``` is not batch file code, it is powershell script code, (apart from `%FILENAME%` which is a variable as understood in a batch file)! It appears to me as if your effort/research has thus far not been sufficient, prior to you coming here. How about you use the search facility at the top of the page to assist you further.

Comment: As a side note, if the file isn't too big to be held in memory, you may be better doing it like this, ```%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile "(Get-Content '%FILENAME%.txt' -Raw) -Replace '"' | Set-Content ..."```

Comment: Hahaha, yeah i'm really new to batch as of coincident i'm designing this program for a project and nothing online seems to be helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the "writer-program", to actually write a string to a file, needs to contain the `>` or the `>>` "symbol" (I don't know how to name it lol).
If you used one of these symbols by coding like

```
echo "%input_from_user%">hello.txt
```

you would probably end up with the text in "hello.txt" written between quotes.
This is due to the presence of the quotes after the `echo` command, and I can tell you that you can safely remove those ones by ending up like

```
echo %input_from_user%>hello.txt
```

(NOTE: if you leave a space between the second "%" sign and the ">" you will end up with a space at the end of the string written to "hello.txt")

I didn't actually provide a solution regarding how to search for "" and deleting them, but I hope that removing them from the original command will help.

Comment: HI! really appreciate your response, however as the text I'm inserting looks something like this

[ echo "|| No.%NO% | %SDUT% | %OS% | %IT% | %TC% | %OTH%">> %FILENAME%.txt ]

which contain special character ( | ) hence if i remove the ( "" ) it won't be translated, any suggestion on this?

Comment: Yeah, maybe you can try to remove the " " and add a little '^' before each  '|'.
 You will end up with something like   [ echo ^|^| No.%NO% ^| %SDUT% ^| %OS% ^| %IT% ^| %TC% ^| %OTH%>> %FILENAME%.txt ].
And you're basically telling Windows to handle those '|' as they were text and not an argument.


(don't know why but markdown doesn't work sorry)